# Rails -v command gives me rails isn't installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

However `rails -v` command gives me rails isn't installed,i found rails gem in this path `/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems`

Comment: did you try `sudo gem install rails` and then `rails -v`

Comment: Really, I am at online server that hosts a website written in rails, so it should  should have rails installed.

Comment: `bundle show rails` will show you rails right? in the bundler path

Comment: Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources

Answer (score 1):

Sounds quite obvious that you should then add `/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems` to your PATH for it to be available as "global" command. This can be done with something like

```
cd /bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.0.20/bin/rails
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

Comment: When go to `/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems` and write `rails -v` it gives me rails is not installed also.

Comment: Are you sure that the _rails_ executable is straight under that folder? I'd assume that it is under some `bin/` folder.

Comment: /bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.0.20/bin/rails ? is this the rails executable?

Comment: That sounds about right. You can of course easily test that by running the `rails -v` under that _bin_ directory. If it is, then just add that directory to your _PATH_.

Comment: Under bin , i ran `rails -v` it gives me `The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Ask your administrator to install one of them
`

Comment: How about `./rails -v`?

Comment: I am at online server which host a website written in rails, Is this command will have a side effect ?

Comment: The dot and slash (_./_) in front of the command just tell to look for the command in the directory you currently are, so no there are no side effects.

Comment: produces = > /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory

Comment: Well, that sound like no ruby was found in your system, try to do the same thing for that: Try `ruby -v` and if it fails, locate the ruby executable from your system and run the above command for it.

Comment: The website is owned by user called `webistrano` being under bin director and write `rails -v` produces ` /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory` but when i switch to `root` and go to `/home/webistrano/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.0.20/bin` and write `rails -v` it gives me `/opt/ruby/1.9.3/p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
from  /opt/ruby/1.9.3/p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' from ./rails:8:in `rescue in <main>' from ./rails:3:in `<main>'`

Comment: It is quite impossible to know more about that. It seems that Ruby or/and Rails isn't installed properly. Sorry.